# How to make this query?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

Teams

- id
- name

Games

- id
- date
- idlocal
- idvisitor

idlocal and idvisitor are the id of the teams in the teams table.

I need to make a SQL query that returns the date, the NAME of the first team, and the NAME of the second team, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT date,t1.name,t2.name FROM 
games g 
INNER JOIN teams t1 on t1.id=g.idlocal
INNER JOIN teams t2 on t2.id=g.idvisitor
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to change it, but worked! `SELECT date,t1.name,t2.name FROM 
GAMES g 
INNER JOIN Teams t1 on g.idlocal=t1.id
INNER JOIN Teams t2 on g.idvisitor=t2.id`